# Parse the HTTP String

Tags: c, string, http, parsing, get

How can I parse this string `GET /STA/ID=HelloWorld/Pass=Testin123 HTTP/1.1` First I need to check for `STA`, if it exists, continue to scan the string. Put Value of `ID` in this case `HelloWorld` should be store in char data type `SSID` and Value of `Pass`, in this case `Testin123` should be store in char data type `Pass`

It should confirm the presence of `STA` in string first. If it is not present, do not enter into loop. If it exits, search for `ID` and `Pass`. Store it.

Now the problem is I am unable to store value of `ID`and `pass`. Also unable to search for `STA`.

```
char GetString[] = "GET /STA/ID=Test/Pass=123 HTTP/1.1";

char *get = strtok(GetString, " ");
char *request = strtok(NULL, " ");
char *rtype = strtok(NULL, " ");
char *FirstPart;

int main()
{
 if (request != NULL)
 {
  FirstPart = strtok(request,"/");
  while(FirstPart)
   {
   if (!strncmp(part, "STA"))
       {
         //Print STA Found

          if(!strncmp(part, "ID=", 3))
             {
              //Store value of ID
             }

           if(!strncmp(part, "Pass=", 5))
             {
             //Store the Pass
             }
          }
       }
       FirstPart =strtok(NULL,'/');
   }
 }
```

Comment: That's a weird place to stop, you got the tokenizing right but didn't test for string equality with strcmp?

Comment: @covener I have added the full code.

Comment: The problem is that the minor errors are hiding your major error.  There's an invalid call to strncmp, with no length argument.  There's an invalid call to strtok with a character second argument, which should be a string.  Your while loop is stepping through the tokens, but only does anything if that token is "STA", but if it is it then checks if it's something else, but you know it's "STA" so the other if clauses can't ever match.

Comment: Is this a school project - if yes, ignore my comment. `strtok` isn't thread safe. If you're running a concurrent web-server, you might run into difficult to debug issues this way. I would avoid these functions when possible. I would also consider using an existing library for this, the cost of a poorly written custom parser is probably higher then the cost of reviewing a fully parsed HTTP request after the fact.

Comment: @Myst No, this not a school Project. I need  reliable way of parsing strings. Any link of library would be of great help!

Comment: @MAP How can I rectify the errors?

Comment: Well, each of the syntax errors I pointed out are fixed in an obvious way.  The call with a missing argument you fix by giving it that argument.  The call with the wrong type argument you fix by changing it to the right type, etc.  If you can't fix these minor errors on inspection, maybe you need to attend a programming class.

Comment: I looked over [Pico HTTP parser](https://github.com/h2o/picohttpparser) (which I recommend) and [the Node.js parser](https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser) (which would probably be slower) when I was looking for a library. I ended up rolling my own (more lenient) parser, but it was probably the nth time I wrote one by then, you can have a look at [the source code here](https://github.com/boazsegev/c-server-tools/blob/master/src/http/http1_simple_parser.c). It's part of [a server library for x86 architectures (Linux/OS X/BSD)](https://github.com/boazsegev/c-server-tools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed a bit of clean-up. One hint: switch all warnings and errors on with your compiler, they exist for a reason. Your code didn't even compile and that is the minimal condition here.

But nevertheless:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char GetString[] = "GET /STA/ID=Test/Pass=123 HTTP/1.1";
  // you cannot do it globally in that way, so I pulled it all into main()
  char *request, *FirstPart;
  // please don't use all upper-case for normal variables
  // I did it for some clarity here
  char *ID, *PASS;

  // skip "GET"
  strtok(GetString, " ");
  // get first part
  request = strtok(NULL, " ");

  if (request != NULL) {
    FirstPart = strtok(request, "/");
    // check for base condition
    if (!strncmp(FirstPart, "STA", 3)) {
      //Print STA Found
      printf("STA = %s\n", FirstPart);
    } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "STA not found!\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    FirstPart = strtok(NULL, "/");
    // graze the key-value combinations
    while (FirstPart) {
      // We check them all here, one after the other
      if (!strncmp(FirstPart, "ID=", 3)) {
    //Store value of ID
    ID = strchr(FirstPart, '=');
    // ID is now "=Test", so skip '='
    ID++;
    printf("ID = %s, value of ID = %s\n", FirstPart, ID);
      } else if (!strncmp(FirstPart, "Pass=", 5)) {
    //Store the Pass
    PASS = strchr(FirstPart, '=');
    // PASS is now "=123", so skip '='
    PASS++;
    printf("PASS = %s, value of PASS = %s\n", FirstPart, PASS);
      } else {
    printf("Unknown part \"%s\", ignoring\n", FirstPart);
      }
      FirstPart = strtok(NULL, "/");
    }
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "No input at all\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The pointers `ID` and `PASS` point to the null-terminated values only, they are not independent memory. You might use `malloc()` to get some and measure the amount with `strlen()`. With `ID` as the example: `ptr_to_mem_for_ID = malloc(strlen(ID));`